# Вопрос по созданию меню

Tags: android, java

Всем привет! Учу помаленьку разработку на Android. Создаю меню! Вроде получается! Создаю в методе

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu).
```

Создаю через add. Возвращаю меню

```
retyrn super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
```

Так вот вопрос. Что такое `super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)`? Хотелось бы понять логически, а не тупо писать код.

Спасибо всем!

Comment: дам совет - прочитай сперва книжку "java 7 the complete reference". Хотябы первую часть(300 страниц). Автор Герберт Шилдт. на русском книжка называется "Java 7 полное руководство". Дело в том что ты учишь Яву непоследовательно - не зная основ, лезешь в андроид.

Comment: @argamidon, да это не только Java касается. Тут лучше почитать книжки по ООП )

Comment: @argamidon,  Ок 300 страниц прочитаю) Просто ужасно хочется научиться на android работать. По ООП в принципе знаком, кодил на PHP. Поэтому принцип понимаю, что, как и где. Я понимаю, что да, функция возвращает menu. Просто не понимаю, почему именно super. Это что за суперкласс такой?)))

Comment: Слово super - это указатель на тот класс, от которого ты наследовался. Т.е. от какого класса ты писал extends - вызывается базовая версия метода, унаследованного класса. В той книжке об этом рассказывается и очень толково и доходчиво.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
```

Это вызов метода базового класса, чтобы корректная инициализация меню была.

Это относится и к остальным методам: onResume(), onStop() и т.п.

Comment: Почему нельзя просто написать return onCreateOptionsMenu(menu), а обязатльно super.?

Comment: @duddeniska, потому что тогда не будет вызван метод базового класса, где есть код по инициализации меню.

Comment: @falstaf, а если бы там что-то серьёзное делалось? Я говорил про переопределение методов в целом, а не только про конкретный пример.

Comment: @falstaf, btw,  у Activity:

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (mParent != null) {
            return mParent.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }
        return true;
    }